# Some problem to store generic struct with PAT in array

Tags: swift, generics

I have a simple protocol for any kind of diffable models:

```
protocol PSDiffableModelProtocol: Hashable {
  var identifier: UUID { get }
}

extension PSDiffableModelProtocol {
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { hasher.combine(identifier) }

  static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool { lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier }
}
```

Well and actually the structure implementing this Protocol:

```
struct PSModel1: PSDiffableModelProtocol, Decodable {
    let identifier = UUID()
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let additionalSubtitle: String
    let imageUrl: URL
    let footnote: String?
 }

struct PSModel2: PSDiffableModelProtocol, Decodable { /* ... */ }

// ....
```

Each model must be stored in another diffable model:

```
struct PSSection<Model: PSDiffableModelProtocol>: PSDiffableModelProtocol {
  let identifier = UUID()
  let title: String?
  let subtitle: String?
  let models: [Model]
}
```

And then there is a simple question, but how do I store my sections in a single place? Like that:

```
var sections: [PSSection] = [
  PSSection(..., models: [PSModel1(...), PSModel1(...), ]),
  PSSection(..., models: [PSModel2(...), PSModel2(...), ]),
  // ...
]
```

Comment: you want to store sections with different generic types?

Comment: @GringoRusso Yes.

Comment: Suppose that the most correct approach is determine **var sections: [PSDiffableModelProtocol]**

Comment: @GringoRusso I got error: Protocol 'PSDiffableModelProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Comment: What code will use `sections`? What interface do you need the elements to have in order for your accessing algorithm to work? `for section in sections { ...what...? }` (Start with the calling code, and work back to the generics and protocols that allow that. Don't start with protocols and try to figure out the calling code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store [PSSection] because compiler should know generic type on compilation time, not runtime.

The most preferred approach is to use **Type Erasure**

```swift
protocol PSDiffableModelProtocol: Hashable {
    var identifier: UUID { get }
}

extension PSDiffableModelProtocol {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { hasher.combine(identifier) }

    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool { lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier }
}

struct TodayModel1: PSDiffableModelProtocol, Decodable {
    let identifier = UUID()
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let additionalSubtitle: String
    let imageUrl: URL
    let footnote: String?

    init() {
        title = ""
        subtitle = ""
        additionalSubtitle = ""
        imageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "")
        footnote = ""
    }
}

struct TodayModel2: PSDiffableModelProtocol, Decodable {
    var identifier: UUID = UUID()
}

struct Section<Model: PSDiffableModelProtocol>: PSDiffableModelProtocol {
    let identifier = UUID()
    let title: String?
    let subtitle: String?
    let models: [Model]
}

struct AnyPSDiffableModelProtocol {

    private let _identifier: () -> UUID // or implement a function

    var idenifier: UUID { return _identifier() }

    init<Type: PSDiffableModelProtocol>(_ another: Type) {
        _identifier = { another.identifier }
    }
}

var sections: [AnyPSDiffableModelProtocol] = []


sections.append(.init(Section(title: "title", subtitle: "subtitle", models: [TodayModel1(), TodayModel1()])))
sections.append(.init(Section(title: "title", subtitle: "subtitle", models: [TodayModel2(), TodayModel2()])))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!(Спасибо!) This works too:  var sections: [AnyHashable]

Comment: I've updated my answer. Well, actually AnyHashable is Type Erasure for Hashable protocol.